# How to reference image stored in directory in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a set of png images (16x16) stored in a folder that's on my web server. Path: c:/wamp/www/website/images/flags . These images represent the different flags of the world's countries.

I want to have access to these images dynamically when I'll output the list of countries and their respective flags in a table through a PHP script.

In my database I have created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  countryCode CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
  countryName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  phoneCode CHAR (3) NOT NULL, 
  imagePathName VARCHAR (254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

How does image referencing work in such a case? Do I store the path just like any CSS or HTML ?

Should I have to store a path, do I simply add it in the following form:

```
INSERT INTO country VALUES ('', 'CD', 
'Democratic Republic of Congo, '243',   'c:/wamp/www/website/images/flags/cd.png')
```

or must I have a column with a BLOB data type. Should that be the case how will the INSERT statement look like ?

Comment: If you are storing a path you should be able to store it like any other string, you'd only need a BLOB if you were storing the actual image.

Comment: In other words, 'yes'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Mahesh's suggestion:

Here's the code

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','fortesting') or die (mysqli_error($dbc)); 

$query = "SELECT countryCode AS 'Code', countryName AS 'Name', filename AS 'Flag' 
FROM country";

$execute = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result['Name'] ?> </td>
                <td><img src="images/flags/<?php echo $result['Flag']?>.png"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my table I have three main columns which are countryCode, countryName and filename. I inserted a few values such as:

```
INSERT INTO country (countryCode, countryName, filename) VALUES
('DZ', 'Algeria', 'dz');
```

The while() loop displays the content of the MySQL table.

In the first column of the HTML table the name of the country is displayed through:

```
<td><?php echo $result['Name'] ?> </td>
```

In the second column of the HTML table the file name of the flag that represents that country is printed inside a URL link:

```
<td><img src="images/flags/<?php echo $result['Flag']?>.png"></td>
```

The names of the countries and flags are displayed dynamically. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

my recommendation is as follows

1 don't store images in  My sql DB. it will increase the db size( page count) and it will impact on DB performance

2 store image folder path in your config file (PHP)

3 store only the image name or id in the database table and using your app you can combine name + path and get the full image path

i think this will make sense to you

Comment: blob ,medium and large text data type can slow down the db performance

Comment: Thank you very much Mahesh. I have an idea of how I can work around that by only saving the image name in the database. I will post the final result when I'm done.

Comment: @Broda-man yes please add it as answer and it will help others to get an idea im a database engineer so i gave some suggestion form DB side but not application end